# IllegalArgumentException: com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider is no org.apache.myfaces.spi.AnnotationProvider

Tags: jsf, websphere, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I am trying to deploy an application on Websphere 8.5.5
I've created a shared library for Websphere that includes myfaces 2.2 jars and other dependencies like commons-collections.
I also made the class loader of my application as PARENT_LAST.
When I deploy the application, I get this exception:

```
An error occured while initializing MyFaces: Class com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider is no org.apache.myfaces.spi.AnnotationProvider
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider is no org.apache.myfaces.spi.AnnotationProvider
at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:557)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:524)
```

Comment: The mentioned procedure works fine with Mojarra 2.2. I am using a shared library containing only: jsf-api-2.2.4 and jsf-impl-2.2.4

Comment: How are you attaching the shared library? are you attaching it to the server instance, or to the application?

Comment: Environment/Shared libraries/New

Comment: and in the application: Shared library references/and add the shared library from the list

Comment: Did you set the Shared Library as an isolated one?

Comment: Have you tried to switch off default IBM JSF implementation and turn on Sun RI implementation? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tweb_jsf.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.0.0%2F1-11-37-0-2-2&lang=en

Comment: The mentioned procedure works fine with Mojarra 2.2. So I finished by using Mojarra instead of Myfaces, and everything worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at running a newer version of MyFaces on WAS 8.5.5, and ran into a similar issue.  It appears to be a conflict between the code IBM wrote to support its embedded version of MyFaces, and an application- or shared library-provided MyFaces.

IBM provides a way to circumvent this issue.  When WAS 8.0 shipped, it provided a feature to allow select either "SunRI1.2" or "MyFaces" as the server-provided JSF. Setting the default to "SunRI1.2" would remove the server-provided MyFaces from the classpath and allow the developer to provide their own.

1. Select any application
2. Click **JSP and JSF Options**
3. In the **JSF implementation** section, change the drop-down to **SunRI1.2**
4. Click **OK**
5. Save configuration and restart server

Comment: Is there a way to set this in the deployment descriptor? so we don't need to change it after the fact? and potentially have it revert?

Comment: Although it's exposed through the application settings, it actually lives at the server level.  Every application on the same server will be affected.

Comment: Yup figured that out afterwards :) Oh well, good thing we're requesting our own JVM for production - cause people may be upset if we force them to use there own and reverse there loaders jut because we are :)